# How can i switch node versions automatically on windows?

Tags: node.js, nvm, nvm-windows

I'm using two project (front and back) with different node versions i want to start both at the same time

I'm using nvm-windows and of i switch version it switches node versions globally (nvm use [version])
I tried AVN and as i read it isn't supported on windows yet.

I read a lot about deep shell integration but can't find answer of my question.

Comment: strongly recommend you simply align the two projects' node versions. There can't be that good of a reason to have them different

Comment: There is almost never a need to run older versions of node.js. Unlike other languages javascript is very backwards compatible. You can run script written in old beta versions of node.js on node 14 with no issues

Answer (score -1):

You can use nvm (Node Version Manager)
You can follow the below link to install it on windows.
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Hope this helps

Comment: The asker directly states in the question that they are using the application you linked.